# How can I export Graphical Shapes (like ellipse) created in editor, to XAML code?

Tags: xaml

I wish to know that if I create any shape like rectangle or ellipse or any polygon in my graphics editor, then how can I get the XAML Code For that. I mean I create any shape (eg. ellipse) in the editor which I have created. The editor has an option (Export to XAML) in the file menu. Then do I have to write some code for that? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question because you are asking how to get the code for the shape from your editor yet have already mentioned in the same sentence that it has an "Export to XAML" option in the menu.

I am going to assume that you mean "How can I consume the exported XAML code".

You need to export the shape to XAML (save the file somewhere) and open the XAML file that it creates when you export, this will likely be a canvas.

You can then place the canvas within the usercontrol or window that you would like to display it with.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your own editor, you can try `Microsoft Expression Blend` or `Microsoft Visual Studio`, so that while design the shapes in the designer, respective XAML code will also be generated in the same file itself.